# How to find the wave pattern recorded by the microphone

Tags: homework-and-exercises, waves, acoustics, harmonics

Two identical tuning forks, vibrating with identical amplitude at a frequency of 660 Hz, are brought towards a microphone from opposite direction with speeds 1 m/s and 2 m/s respectively.At the time when one tuning fork is 40 cm away from the microphone and the other one is 60 cm, the wave pattern recorded by the microphone is characterized by a

a) frequency of 660 Hz with constant amplitude

b) frequency of 658 Hz with constant amplitude

c) frequency of 662 Hz with constant amplitude

d) frequency close to 660 Hz but amplitude modulating at 2 Hz

e) frequency close to 660 Hz but amplitude modulating at 4 Hz

Attempt at solution:
My reasoning is that, the two oscillations coming from opposite side would set up a standing wave pattern. Therefore, $y(x,t) = (2y_m\sin kx)\cos wt$ which implies that amplitude changes with position. Hence, I eliminate the first three options. The microphone being at one end and the forks approaching from the other end looks like I can take it be a one end closed pipe. However I am not quite sure about this. To make use of the speeds and distances this is the only way I could think of it. 
Could someone please help?!

Edit:
My attempt above is totally incorrect as I ignored the fact that moving sources change the frequency generated in the air and therefore at the detector.
This is a doppler effect problem as pointed out in the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a Doppler effect and beats problem (or a moving interference pattern problem).
It cannot be a standing wave problem because the wavelength and hence the frequency of the sound waves in the air generated by the two moving sources are not the same.
This will mean that the positions of maximum and minimum amplitude will move.

Comment: My first thought to this problem was doppler effect but then it shifted to standing wave as its definition was close to how this question was framed and I completely ignored the fact that moving sources change the perceived frequency. Thank you for pointing it out!

Answer (score 0):

I thought I would write down the solution myself that it may be of help to those who view this question.
I'll call the new frequencies received at the microphone as $\nu_1$ and $\nu_2$

From Doppler effect equation,

For the tuning fork coming at a speed of 1 m/s

$\nu_1$ = $\nu*\frac {344}{343} = 661.92 Hz$

For the tuning fork coming at a speed of 2 m/s

$\nu_2$ = $\nu*\frac {345}{343} = 663.84 Hz$

therefore the beats frequency = 1.92 Hz

The frequency received at the microphone = avg of $\nu_1$ and $\nu_2$ = 662.8 Hz
So the right choice would be c.